# How to update another field when using partial_update?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using partial_updates on my user model, and I wish to change the `is_active` to True on the user model instance when a partial_update happens - even though `is_active` is not exposed to the endpoint. My class looks like this:

```
class UserInvitationUpdate(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = kwargs.get('username')
        token = kwargs.get('token')
        return activated_user(username, token)

    def get_object(self):
        username = self.kwargs.get('username')
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        return user
    
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.kwargs.get('username')
        token = self.kwargs.get('token')

        if my_if_statement_is_true:

            # TODO set user to active 
            # how do I set is_active = True for the user model instance?
            return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple way to deal with that. You could either change your serializer `.save()` method and set manually the field is_active to true, or set it in the view by updating the `perform_update()` method of your view :

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(is_active=True)
```

More info [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save)